# How to put a formula within a function in R?

Tags: r, function, formula

I want to store a dplyr function/formula (e.g. filter(exercise=="Inadequate") or mutate(exercise="adequate") in the variable_to_filter section for my function. I have lots of variables that need to go through this function.  How can I do that? I know the code below doesn't work, but I hope you can see the logic in what I'm trying to do.

```
exercise_inadequate<-(exercise=="Inadequate")
variable_to_mutate<-(mutate(exercise="adequate"))

difference_pe<-function(percent, variable_to_filter, variable_to_mutate){
  filtered <- dataset %>% filter(variable_to_filter)
  sampled <- sample_frac(filtered, percent/100)
  sampled <- sampled %>% mutate(variable_to_mutate)
}

difference_pe(100, exercise_inadequate, exercise_adequate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer passing the column name and value separately to the function because evaluating string as condition in `filter` statement can be ugly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

difference_pe<- function(dataset, percent, col, value) {
   filtered <- dataset %>% filter({{col}} == value)
   sampled <- sample_frac(filtered, percent/100)
   return(sampled)
}
```

You can use this function as :

```
difference_pe(dataset, 100, exercise, "Inadequate")
```

---

If for some reason the above is not possible and you need to pass condition as string we can use `parse_expr` which is similar to `eval` `parse`.

```
exercise_inadequate<- 'exercise=="Inadequate"'

difference_pe<- function(dataset, percent, variable_to_filter) {
   filtered <- dataset %>% filter(eval(parse_expr(variable_to_filter)))
   #filtered <- dataset %>% filter(eval(parse(text = variable_to_filter)))
   sampled <- sample_frac(filtered, percent/100)
   return(sampled)
}


difference_pe(dataset, 100, exercise_inadequate)
```

Comment: thanks so much for helping, I got this error though:

Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  sampled <- sample_frac(filtered, percent/100)
  sampled <- sampled %>% mutate({{variable}} ="

guess it doesnt work for mutate?

Comment: @Bailey `sampled %>% mutate({{variable}} =` isn't a valid R syntax. It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example along with expected output of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I feel like we're really close. I'm trying to do sampled %>% mutate(variable_to_mutate = "Adequate") so that I can input variable_to_mutate and "Adequate" as part of the function

Comment: It works when I do mutate(EXERCISE=mutate_value), but once I substitute exercise for variable_to_mutate (or col in your example), its not working =/

Comment: Try `mutate({{col}} := mutate_value)`

Comment: When you want to evaluate string as column name like here we use `:=`